# How can i automatically add a new column on a datagrid WPF based on a list of users?

Tags: c#, database, wpf, xaml

I'm currently creating a software where i can add users and then calculate their working hours in another window. The window with working hours has a combobox where you can select a specific user or all of them. When the user is selected the datagrid is programmed to show only the column of the selected user. Now i have to implement the fact that when i select all of them, the datagrid should automatically add the columns required for all the users.

This is my datagrid in XAML:

```
     <DataGrid
        Name="DgEsportazione"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding OreDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        BindingGroup="{Binding ListaUtenti}"
        Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle1}">
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Key.DayOfWeek}" Value="Saturday">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Key.DayOfWeek}" Value="Sunday">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="*"
                MinWidth="100"
                Binding="{Binding Key, ConverterCulture='it-IT', StringFormat=dddd dd/MM}"
                Header="Date"
                IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="*"
                MinWidth="100"
                Binding="{Binding Value}"
                Header="Working Hours"
                IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I tried searching on internet but nothing that could help me.

Comment: Do you want to say that different users have different columns?

Comment: yes, when i select in the combobox all the user i want it to autogenerate column for every single user.

Comment: Then why don't simply create a DataTable as data source? DataTable is the best choice when you need dynamic columns. You just create a new DataTable for every user.

Comment: I don't know how to do that because i just started programming. Could you give me an example, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provide any details about your scenario, I can only provide a very general example.

For example, if you use the old Ado.Net API to read data from a database you can read it directly into a [`DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-8.0).

The following example shows how to generate a table that consists of two columns "Username" and "Age" and is populated with two data rows. See `DataTable` [Examples section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-8.0#examples) for more examples.

```cs
// If this property is a member of a control e.g. Window, 
// then this property must be a dependency property.
// Otherwise, this property must raise the 'INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' event.
public DataTable UserData { get; set; }

var newUserTable = new DataTAble();

/* 1) Define two columns: 'username' of type string and 'Age' of type int */
var usernameColumn = new DataColumn("Username", typeof(string));
newUserTable.Columns.Add(usernameColumn);
var userAge = new DataColumn("Age", typeof(int));
newUserTable.Columns.Add(userAge);

/* 2) Add data (rows) to the table.
*     access columns either by index or by column name. */
DataRow firstRow = newUserTable.NewRow();
firstRow["username"] = "User1";
firstRow["Age"] = "100";
newUserTable.Rows.Add(firstRow);

DataRow secondRow = newUserTable.NewRow();
secondRow[0] = "User2";
secondRow[1] = "200";
newUserTable.Rows.Add(secondRow);

// 3) Assign table to the DataGrid either directly or via data binding (recommended)
this.UserTable = newUserTable;
//this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = newUserTable.DefaultView;
```